# Downspout Joint Male-Female Position

Tags: gutters

In a downspout joint, should the female pipe always be down and the male up?

I have recently installed my first downspout and I think I did it wrong by inserting the bottom pipe into the top one, i.e. put the male on the bottom, because now it leaks through the crack in the joint and the wall of the house get really wet.  I was thinking to put sealant in but, since it's not too hard to do, I will just replace the whole downspout and put the bottom in the joint over the pipe above it (male on top, female on bottom).  That way, all the water will be channelled down the downspout and there should be no leaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part where water is flowing *from*, should always go into the part where the water is flowing *to*.

So with a downspout, the the upper tube should go into the lower tube.

Comment: Same is true for ductwork.

Comment: Did exactly the opposite. Live and learn. Will fix tomorrow. Luckily, it's easy

Answer (score 1):

Yes, female on the bottom, always; male on the bottom also helps to plug the gutter/downspout with debris. Does your gutter to downspout connection not lead you in the right path? Most do.

Comment: I messed up. Will redo tomorrow

Comment: Seems like it would be boring having it always the same way.